# Google Sheets App Script Mysterious Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm teaching a class and for my class I keep all of my student's marks on a google spreadsheet. On my website I would like to present information to students on an individual basis. I've created an app where it presents them with a password text box. They type in their password and then it retrieves information from the spreadsheet that is unique to them and presents it to them in a label. I've been trying to hack this all together, but it's just not working properly and I'm getting an error that I cannot diagnose. If I print out the information using Browser.msgBox() it outputs the info, but otherwise it generates an error. Why is this happening and what is the fix? Here's the code:

```
var pointsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1o8_f063j1jYZjFEnI_P7uAztpnEAvQ6mc3Z1_Owa69Y');

//creates and shows an app with a label and password text box
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Incomplete Challenges');

  var mygrid = app.createGrid(1, 2);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Password:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createPasswordTextBox().setName("text"));

  var mybutton = app.createButton('Submit');

  var submitHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('getResults');
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(mygrid);
  mybutton.addClickHandler(submitHandler);

  var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  app.add(mypanel);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app); 
  //return app; //UNCOMMENT WHEN DEPLOYING APP
}

//obtains data based on password entered by user and outputs their info
function getResults(eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Incomplete Challenges');
  var password = eventInfo.parameter.text;

  var passwordCheckRange = pointsSheet.getRange("B34:C34").getValues();

  if (passwordCheckRange == null) {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Range is null");
    return app;
  }

  var name;
  for(var i = 0; i < passwordCheckRange.length; i++) {
    if(passwordCheckRange[i][1] == password) {
      name = passwordCheckRange[i][0];
      break;
    }
  }

  var studentRecordRange = pointsSheet.getRange("B3:AY29").getValues();
  var headingRange = pointsSheet.getRange("B1:AY2").getValues();

  if (studentRecordRange == null) {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Range is null");
    return app;
  }

  var requestedRecord;
  for(var i = 0; i < studentRecordRange.length; i++) {
    if(studentRecordRange[i][0] == name)
      requestedRecord = studentRecordRange[i];
  }

  var stringRecord = "";
  for(var i = headingRange[1].length-1; i >= 7; i--) {
    if (requestedRecord[i] == "")
      stringRecord += headingRange[1][i] + ": " + headingRange[0][i] + "XP" + "\\n";
  }

  var mygrid = app.createGrid(2, 1);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('INCOMPLETE CHALLENGES'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel(stringRecord));

  var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  app.add(mypanel);


  //Browser.msgBox(stringRecord);
  return app;
}
```

The error that I experience is: **Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred.**

As you can see it's very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 28 it should be ***getActiveApplication***() and not ***createApplication()***. 
You cant create an application on another application. :)

Also I think line 63 it should be `"<br>";` instead "\n"; along with  line 68 it should be  **createHTML** instead of  **createLabel**

I also think that you have apply few styling css so that your app looks good. check on .setStyleAttributes in UiApp.

Comment: **...so that your app looks look.** ? please re-read and rewrite.

Comment: So I should change:
`var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();`
TO
`var mypanel = app.createHTML();`?

or were you referring to changing one of these lines?
`mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('INCOMPLETE CHALLENGES'));`
`mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel(stringRecord));`

I'm a little lost

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what you were saying. Thank you for the help...much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in this code, the first one -that generates the error you get - is (as mentioned in the other answer) the `UiApp.createApplication()` in the handler function.

You can't create an UiApp instance in a handler function, you should instead get the active instance and eventually add elements to it (using `UiApp.getActiveApplication()`).

You can't neither change the title of this instance. Btw, it doesn't make sense since this title will not appear as a "title" when you will be deploying this app as a webapp. It will simply show up at the top of your browser window (as a page title) as your app will occupy the whole screen and not a modal popup anymore. So if you want a title to appear in your Ui, simply add it as an HTML widget where you can choose the font size and weight (and any other CSS styles).

The other error is in the password check, you are using `Browser.msgBox("Error: Range is null");` but Browser class won't work in UiApp.  You should only use UiApp elements, not spreadSheetApp elements.

And, as a more general comment, I suggest you test your app directly using the .dev url (last saved version) of the app (after saving a beta version and having deployed it) so that you are in the "real" use condition and have a pertinent pov on the result.